# How to plot a scatter plot with a legend label for each class

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, scatter-plot

I am interested in plotting a legend in my scatterplot. My current code looks like this

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]
classes = [2,4,4,2]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=classes, label=classes)
plt.legend()
```

The problem is that when the plot is created, the legend is shown as an array instead of showing the unique labels and their classes.

[image: This is how the plot looks]

I am aware this is a question discussed previously in threads such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558816/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-legend), however, I feel my problem is simpler, and the solution there does not fit. Also, in that example the person is specifying the colors, however, in my case, I do know beforehand how many colors I'll need. Moreover, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940/matplotlib-scatter-plot-legend) example, the user is creating multiple scatters, each one with a unique color. Again, this is not what I want. My goal is to simply create the plot using an `x, y` array, and the labels. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually both linked questions provide a way how to achieve the desired result.

The easiest method is to create as many scatter plots as unique classes exist and give each a single color and legend entry.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]
classes = [2,4,4,2]
unique = list(set(classes))
colors = [plt.cm.jet(float(i)/max(unique)) for i in unique]
for i, u in enumerate(unique):
    xi = [x[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    yi = [y[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, c=colors[i], label=str(u))
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

In case the classes are string labels, the solution would look slightly different, in that you need to get the colors from their index instead of using the classes themselves.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]
classes = ['X','Y','Z','X']
unique = np.unique(classes)
colors = [plt.cm.jet(i/float(len(unique)-1)) for i in range(len(unique))]
for i, u in enumerate(unique):
    xi = [x[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    yi = [y[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, c=colors[i], label=str(u))
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe manually filling a `table` could be useful here. Another idea is using `colorbar` if your classes are contiguous numbers. I'm showing both approaches in one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
classes = [2,4,4,2,1,3,5]
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("viridis",5)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=classes, label=classes,cmap=cmap,vmin=0.5,vmax=5.5)
plt.colorbar()
unique_classes = list(set(classes))
plt.table(cellText=[[x] for x in unique_classes], loc='lower right',
          colWidths=[0.2],rowColours=cmap(np.array(unique_classes)-1),
         rowLabels=['label%d'%x for x in unique_classes],
          colLabels=['classes'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest solution is to use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), a high-level API for `matplotlib`, which separates groups by color, using the `hue` parameter.

  - [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) - axes-level function.
  - [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with `kind='scatter'` (default) - figure-level function.
  - See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)
- `legend='full'`: ensures every group will get an entry in the legend, which is important when the when the `hue` category is numeric.
- If using the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) distribution, seaborn will already be installed in the `(base)` environment. Otherwise use `pip` to install for non-Anaconda environments.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 3.5))

sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, hue=classes, legend='full', ax=ax)
```

[image]

```py
g = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', x=x, y=y, hue=classes, legend='full', height=3.5, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

---

- Optionally, create a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) from the lists of data, and then plot with seaborn.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'classes': classes})

# axes level plot
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='classes', legend='full')

# figure level plot
g = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='classes', legend='full')
```