# Use Matplotlib to color points based on a value

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a dateframe df, containing two continuous features X1, X2 and a boolean categorical feature, X3.  How can I draw a scatterplot with X1, X2 along each axis, with the color of each datapoint determined by the value of the boolean (eg, say "red" if X3 is True, "blue" if False).

Comment: I guess as the answer does not report about the actual problem, this can indeed by savely closed as duplicate. If you have a problem implementing a solution, please share a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I had already read the topic you claim is a duplicate:  however, it doesn't seem to answer the question of how I can assign a color on the basis of a categorical (rather than continuous) variable.   Am I missing something?

Comment: And I'm not sure what "Importance" means:  should I actually write one line of pseudo code to restate the question???

Comment: The problem is solvable using the answer to the linked question. You should not add some pseudocode but instead a [mcve] of the code that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: You may also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868204/mention-label-in-matplotlib-plot-based-on-categorical-class).