# Scatterplot legend from color dict python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter

For the `df` below, I'm trying to alter the `legend` of the `scatter plot` to display `Column C` values.

It works when the values are floats but when I try to insert strings it returns a ValueError. `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
      'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'B' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,7,7,7,7],     
     #'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],  #Doesn't work 
      'C' : [2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,2],    # Works
      })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['A']
y = df['B']
classes = df['C']
unique = list(set(classes))
colors = [plt.cm.jet(float(i)/max(unique)) for i in unique]
for i, u in enumerate(unique):
    xi = [x[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    yi = [y[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, c=colors[i], label=str(u))
plt.legend()
```

Thus far, when trying to use the strings I've tried to change `float` to `str` (as below):

```
colors = [plt.cm.jet(float(i)/max(unique)) for i in unique]
colors = [plt.cm.jet(str(i)/max(unique)) for i in unique]
```

It returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`

Intended Output (But I would like to have strings in the legend, so `'X','Y','Z'` instead of `2,4,6`):

[image]

Comment: You can't divide a string. That is, you can't use the operator `/` on a string like 'Z'. Also, your code `colors = [plt.cm.jet(str(i)/max(unique)) for i in unique]` is converting `i` to a string, and in that case `i` is already a string. Could you explain what you want to obtain?

Comment: @nahusznaj updated

Comment: I updated [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057207/4124317) from which you got the idea to be able to use strings as classes. Of course you cannot use strings for index a colormap, but need to use numbers instead.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what @Maxibon wanted to do and had something to add but since I can't submit an answer, here's the lines I think you could change to obtain something `colors = [plt.cm.flag(i) for i,u in enumerate(unique)]` `for i, u in enumerate(unique):    xi = [x[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]     yi = [y[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if classes[j] == u]    plt.scatter(xi, yi, c=colors[i], label=str(u))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, spot on.

Comment: @nahusznaj `flag` is a cyclic colormap, I don't think this will help here, because you would want to have unique colors. In general you may of course index the colormap (calling it with integers), but that requires some prior knowledge about the number of colors in that map, so I think the proposed solution in the other answer is still more versatile in general.

Comment: I agree. I didn't put much thought into choosing jet for my answer.