# Is there a quick way to set the legend of a scatterplot without looping?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have 3 arrays like so:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,4,3,2,1]
c = [0,0,1,0,1]

plt.figure(figsize = (12,9))

plt.scatter(x = x, y = y, c = c)

plt.legend(['0', '1'])
```

I'm able to generate a scatterplot like this:
[image]

But what I want is for it to differentiate the colors between 0 and 1.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056713/matplotlib-scatterplot-with-legend?fbclid=IwAR0pmCC_ADEVE5DGsiZGqR_iM1HK2JUXM80y9_LuiZmj90vGONKe7VrtpCU) does a for loop over the classes to achieve the desired result.
I've also tried iterating over the `plt.scatter()` object but it's not iterable.

Is there some sort of simple solution out there? preferably no loops and only about 1 line of code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No yet. But Matplotlib will soon release a version of scatter with a straightforward [scatter + legend](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) with no need for multiple calls.

Note that you can also use [the Seaborn scatterplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/%60generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) that you use to generate a scatterplot with labels in one single line (see below from the Seaborn documentation):

```py
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop and plot all different sets of data one by one with appropriate label.
Here I am plotting the red dots then the green ones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,4,3,2,1]
c = [0,0,1,0,1]

unique = list(set(c))
colors = ['red','green']
for i, u in enumerate(unique):
    xi = [x[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if c[j] == u]
    yi = [y[j] for j  in range(len(x)) if c[j] == u]
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, c=colors[i], label=str(u))
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, but the question was to achieve it _without looping_...