# How to manually create a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I am using matplotlib and I would like to manually add items to the legend that are a color and a label. I am adding data to to the plot to specifying there would lead to a lot of duplicates.

My thought was to do:

```
    ax2.legend(self.labels,colorList[:len(self.labels)])
    plt.legend()
```

Where self.labels is the number of items I want legend lables for that takes a subset of the large color list. However this yields nothing when I run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom legend in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303928/how-to-make-custom-legend-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 193):

Have you checked the [Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)?

For practicality, I quote the example from the [guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists).

> Not all handles can be turned into legend entries automatically, so it
>   is often necessary to create an artist which can. Legend handles don’t
>   have to exists on the Figure or Axes in order to be used.
>
> Suppose we wanted to create a legend which has an entry for some data
>   which is represented by a red color:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**

To add two patches you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='The blue data')

plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])
```

[image]

Answer (score 146):

For those wanting to add manual legend items into a single/common legend with automatically generated items:

```
#Imports
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# where some data has already been plotted to ax
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# manually define a new patch 
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='Manual Label')

# handles is a list, so append manual patch
handles.append(patch) 

# plot the legend
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc='upper center')
```

Example of common legend with manual and auto-generated items:
[image: example of common legend with manual and auto-generated items]

##### ADDED 2021-05-23 (amended 2023-04-21 to include points)

complete example with manual line, patch, and points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# from data
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40], label='My Data (line)', color='red')
plt.scatter([2.5], [15], label='My Data (scatter point)', color='b') # plotting single point via scatter
plt.plot([3.5], [20], label= ' My Data (plot point)', marker='o', markersize=10, 
         markeredgecolor='k', markerfacecolor='g', linestyle='') # plotting single point via plot with null linestyle

# access legend objects automatically created from data
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

# create manual symbols for legend
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='manual patch')   
line = Line2D([0], [0], label='manual line', color='k')
point = Line2D([0], [0], label='manual point', marker='s', markersize=10, 
         markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='k', linestyle='')

# add manual symbols to auto legend
handles.extend([patch, line, point])

plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 71):

Here's a solution which let's you control the width and style of your legend lines (among [a lot of other things](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

colors = ['black', 'red', 'green']
lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c, linewidth=3, linestyle='--') for c in colors]
labels = ['black data', 'red data', 'green data']
plt.legend(lines, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: output of the code above]

For even more options, take a look at this [matplotlib gallery sample](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html).

Answer (score 31):

I'm adding some code to build on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029132/gabra and the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/5946578/brady-forcier. Here, I manually add elements to a legend *via* a 'for' loop.

First I create a dictionary with my legend names and desired colours. I actually do this as I load in my data, but here I'm just explicitly defining:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

legend_dict = { 'data1' : 'green', 'data2' : 'red', 'data3' : 'blue' }
```

Then I loop through the dictionary and for each entry define a patch and append to a list, 'patchList'. I then use this list to create my legend.

```
patchList = []
for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(color=legend_dict[key], label=key)
        patchList.append(data_key)

plt.legend(handles=patchList)
plt.savefig('legend.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Here's my output:
[image: legend example]

I'm not bothered about the legend entries being in a particular order, but you could probably achieve this with

```
plt.legend(handles=sorted(patchList))
```

This is my first answer, so apologies in advance for any errors/faux pas.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing this out:

```
def plot_bargraph_with_groupings(df, groupby, colourby, title, xlabel, ylabel):
    """
    Plots a dataframe showing the frequency of datapoints grouped by one column and coloured by another.
    df : dataframe
    groupby: the column to groupby
    colourby: the column to color by
    title: the graph title
    xlabel: the x label,
    ylabel: the y label
    """

    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

    # Makes a mapping from the unique colourby column items to a random color.
    ind_col_map = {x:y for x, y in zip(df[colourby].unique(),
                               [plt.cm.Paired(np.arange(len(df[colourby].unique())))][0])}


    # Find when the indicies of the soon to be bar graphs colors.
    unique_comb = df[[groupby, colourby]].drop_duplicates()
    name_ind_map = {x:y for x, y in zip(unique_comb[groupby], unique_comb[colourby])}
    c = df[groupby].value_counts().index.map(lambda x: ind_col_map[name_ind_map[x]])

    # Makes the bargraph.
    ax = df[groupby].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',
                                         figsize=FIG_SIZE,
                                         title=title,
                                         color=[c.values])
    # Makes a legend using the ind_col_map
    legend_list = []
    for key in ind_col_map.keys():
        legend_list.append(mpatches.Patch(color=ind_col_map[key], label=key))

    # display the graph.
    plt.legend(handles=legend_list)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
```