# How to put all legend entries on one line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I can't seem to find a solution.
I have a legend that's custom (using solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39500265/)) and I'm trying to put multiple entries on one line rather than have each new entry under the previous one.
How does one do?

```
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='The blue data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])
```

I'd like to have "(red marker) The red data, (blue marker) The blue data, etc..." all in one line on top. It'd be nice to have it start a new line too when there are more entries than can fit on the plot. So just like normal text I guess.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to have `n` columns in the legend, you can use

```
plt.legend(ncol=n)
```

Comment: There isn't an actual legend though, so if I do that, I get an error: `"UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots. warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. ""`

Comment: nevermind, it totally worked ... \*facepalm\* ... I was confusing rows with columns and kept wondering why `ncol=1` didn't make one line ... I guess this'll do. Thanks!

Comment: +1. It would be good to indicate there is no general option to have one line (without adjusting manually the number of columns when a plot is added), if this is the case.