# Color based legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

My question goes as follows:

Imagine I have four lists `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. I want to plot them by using the same radial grid `R`. For some reason `a`, `b` share a common property X and `c`, `d` share Y. Therefore I want `a`, `b` and `c`, `d` to appear in the same color respectively (green and blue), and I just want two labels to appear into the legend: one being green and resembling X and the other blue and resembling Y. Any ideas of a simple method to do it? An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a =[2,4,6,8,10]
b =[3,6,9,12,15]
c =[1,4,9,16,25]
d =[1,8,27,64,125]
R =[0,1,2,3,4]

plt.plot(R,a,color ='green')
plt.plot(R,b,color ='green')
plt.plot(R,c,color ='blue')
plt.plot(R,d,color ='blue')
plt.legend('blue'= X,'green'=Y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label **only** the objects you want to display in the legend once instead of manually setting the legends as following. I also replaced `color ='green'` by a shorter syntax `'-g'`, same for the blue color.

```
# Your imports and data here

plt.plot(R,a,'-g', label='X')
plt.plot(R,b,'-g')
plt.plot(R,c,'-b', label='Y')
plt.plot(R,d,'-b')
plt.legend(fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Alternate way** Without putting `label='X'` and `label='Y'` while plotting

```
leg = plt.legend(['X', 'Y'], fontsize=18)
colors=['green', 'blue']

for i, j in enumerate(leg.legendHandles):
    j.set_color(colors[i])
```

Comment: Sure!  Thanks , i don't know why i was thinking about a more complicated answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I edited your question because you wrote green for Y and blue for X, but you used other way round in your code.

Comment: Strange that people go downvoting for no reason.

Comment: I realized would need a more general way to do it ( if there is one) . My example is just a simplified version of my problem . On reality i am dealing with  an interface with several plots and buttons involved, and I have loop where  i perform the plots inside. Then it comes the problem , namely that i can not set the legend just once.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add more details to your question

Comment: Alternative way just created one legend on plot for me and then I solved this via making patches for each label and color as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/how-to-manually-create-a-legend