# Coloring bar chart by category of the values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to color my bar plot by the values' category. Is that possible using Matplotlib?

Example:
Normally I use two list to create a bar chart:
values = [5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 12]
xticks = [John, Nina, Darren, Peter, Joe, Kendra]

Is it possible to add an extra category list, and color those bars based on those categories?
Like:
category = [male, female, male, male, male, female]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but how do you want the colouring to be done? Should each member of a category have the same colour...? (then why not group them together?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you could structure your data as a dictionary, then it could be solved like this, where each entry as a property "gender" which is also the lookup key in the dictionar `color_map` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)

data={
    0:{"name":"John",   "value":5, "gender":"male"},
    1:{"name":"Nina",   "value":2, "gender":"female"},
    2:{"name":"Darren", "value":1, "gender":"male"},
    3:{"name":"Peter",  "value":7, "gender":"male"},
    4:{"name":"Joe",    "value":8, "gender":"male"},
    5:{"name":"Kendra", "value":12,"gender":"female"},
}

color_map={"male":"b","female":"r"}

xs=data.keys()
ys=[v["value"] for v in data.values()]
names=[v["name"] for v in data.values()]
colors=[color_map[v["gender"]] for v in data.values()]

ax.bar(xs,ys,color=colors)

ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

---

There are multiple ways to get a valid "male"/"female" legend here; one would be to create a [fully custom legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/manually-add-legend-items-python-matplotlib). Apart form that you could, for example, separate the dict into one for male and one for female data, and then create two separate bar plots like `ax.bar(… , label="male")`, which is kind of a bloated approach, however.

I'd suggest to use the `pandas` library then, changing my answer to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)

data={
    0:{"name":"John",   "value":5, "gender":"male"},
    1:{"name":"Nina",   "value":2, "gender":"female"},
    2:{"name":"Darren", "value":1, "gender":"male"},
    3:{"name":"Peter",  "value":7, "gender":"male"},
    4:{"name":"Joe",    "value":8, "gender":"male"},
    5:{"name":"Kendra", "value":12,"gender":"female"},
}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')

color_map={"male":"b","female":"r"}
df["colors"]=df["gender"].map(color_map)

for g in ["male","female"]:
    xs=df.index[df["gender"]==g]
    ys=df["value"][df["gender"]==g]
    color=df["colors"][df["gender"]==g]
    ## or, perhaps easier in this specific case: 
    #  color=color_map[g]

    ax.bar(xs,ys,color=color,label=g)

ax.legend()
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df["name"])

plt.show()
```

Here, the key is that we can filter the dataframe `df` (think of it perhaps like an Excel worksheet) on various conditions, e.g. `df["value"][df["gender"]=="male"]`. This way we can create the two separate bar plots easily.

Comment: This plots a bar chart.

Comment: @gmds isn't this exactly what the question infers? See: "Coloring bar chart by category of the values", "I need to color my bar plot.." … ?

Comment: Thank you @Asmus, this is exactly what I need! One more question here, is it possible to create a legend based on category, in this case "gender" ?

Comment: @Asmus I use pandas a lot and I like you second solution even more, thanks a lot!