# Pandas: Stacked bar plot with adjacent bars

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Lets say I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
>> df
Period   Income    Expenses   Commissions   
0        12034.23  1665.25    601.59
1        23432.77  2451.33    1521.4
2        62513.12  4210.35    3102.24
```

I'd like to make a stacked bar plot of `Expenses` and `Commissions`, and then have the `Income` column be an adjacent bar next to this stacked column.

I'm familiar with the `df.plot.bar()` method, but I'm not sure how to shift the x-axis values to have the `Income` bar adjacent to the stacked `Expenses` and `Commissions` bars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following: First produce the stacked bar plot and then **use shifted x-values**, where the shift is equal to the stacked-bar width. Additionally, you can add the extra legend for `Income` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551701/4932316) method, if you wish

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

bar_width = 0.25

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df[['Expenses', 'Commissions']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, width=bar_width)
ax.bar(np.arange(len(df))+bar_width, df['Income'], align='center', width=bar_width, color='green')
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 2.5)


handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Income')

handles.append(patch) 

plt.legend(handles=handles, loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I'll mark this as the answer