# Geographic plotting

Tags: plot, geopandas, shapefile

I plotted data using the following code:

```
base = df.plot(color='white', edgecolor='lightgrey')
df2.plot(ax=base, marker='yellow', color='yellow', markersize=5);df3.plot(ax=base, marker='red', color='red', markersize=5);
style={'no-easement': 'yellow', 'easement': 'red'};
```

I got the expected results:
[image]

My question is how can I label the color as a description in the corner of the graph? Suppose: I want to level yellow color as A and Red color as B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually create a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/how-to-manually-create-a-legend)

Comment: see also [@gabra's answer showing how to do this with color patches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500357/3888719), which might be exactly what you're looking for.