# How to add labels to sets of seaborn boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 sets of boxplots, one set in blue color and another in red color. I want the legend to show the label for each set of boxplots, i.e.

Legend:
-blue box- A, -red box- B

Added `labels='A'` and `labels='B'` within `sns.boxplot()`, but didn't work with error message *"No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument"*. How do I add the labels?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUo5T.png)

code for the inserted image:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = list(range(1,13))
n = 40
index = [item for item in x for i in range(n)]

np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.normal(30, 2, len(index)),
                   'B': np.random.normal(10, 2, len(index))},
                   index=index)

red_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='r', marker='D')
blue_dot = dict(markerfacecolor='b', marker='o')

plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])
ax = plt.gca()
ax1 = sns.boxplot( x=df.index, y=df['A'], width=0.5, color='red', \
    boxprops=dict(alpha=.5), flierprops=red_diamond, labels='A')
ax2 = sns.boxplot( x=df.index, y=df['B'], width=0.5, color='blue', \
    boxprops=dict(alpha=.5), flierprops=blue_dot, labels='B')
plt.ylabel('Something')
plt.legend(loc="center", fontsize=8, frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

Here are the software versions I am using: seaborn version 0.11.2. matplotlib version 3.5.1. python version 3.10.1

Comment: Since we don't have the data to classify the colors, we need to create a legend handler and labels. Please refer to [How to manually create a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/how-to-manually-create-a-legend).

Comment: Follow this guide and it works with the following code: `red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='A') 
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='B') 
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch], loc="center right", fontsize=8, frameon=False)`

Comment: @montvinpeck  You could also set alpha and edge color for the patches to make them more similar to the boxplots, e.g. `red_patch = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='black', label='A')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach sets a label via the `boxprops`, and creates a legend using part of `ax.artists`. (Note that `ax`, `ax1` and `ax2` of the question's code are all pointing to the same subplot, so here only `ax` is used.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 13)
index = np.repeat(x, 40)
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.normal(30, 2, len(index)),
                   'B': np.random.normal(10, 2, len(index))},
                  index=index)
red_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='r', marker='D')
blue_dot = dict(markerfacecolor='b', marker='o')

plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='A', width=0.5, color='red',
                 boxprops=dict(alpha=.5, label='A'), flierprops=red_diamond)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='B', width=0.5, color='blue',
            boxprops=dict(alpha=.5, label='B'), flierprops=blue_dot, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Something')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [h for h, lbl, prev in zip(handles, labels, [None] + labels) if lbl != prev]
ax.legend(handles=handles, loc="center", fontsize=8, frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot legend labels from artists]

Alternative approaches could be:

- `pd.melt` the dataframe to long form, so `hue` could be used; a problem here is that then the legend wouldn't take the `alpha` from the `boxprops` into account; also setting different fliers wouldn't be supported
- create a legend from custom handles

Comment: For some reason the legend is not showing when I use your code on my terminal. Don't know why.

Comment: seaborn version 0.11.2. matplotlib version 3.5.1. python version 3.10.1

Comment: I updated the code. Now it should also work for your versions.