# how to make the legend show all str value in list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_axis=(0,10)
y_axis=(0,10)
label = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(type(label))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis,color='none')
plt.plot([label])
plt.legend(label)
plt.show()
```

I made the color = 'none' to clear the lines in the plot. But I want to let all labels in legend have color, what should I do?
when the label is an int list, code runs will, but when I want to make an str list legend, it not works(because plt.plot([label]), get error:TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray')
but if I remove it, the legend only prints the first values.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v9V9.png)

Comment: You will probably need to make a custom legend: [How to make custom legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13303928/7758804) and [Manually add legend Items Python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39500265/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, that first label matches the first line you plot; the second label matches the second line you plot, and so on.  Your output with the "int list" has a "none" colored line for the label '1', just as you specified.  To get a visible (non-clear) line for `1`, you have to specify something that color -- and it will match the first line.

I recommend that you work through the documentation again, paying close attention to the various formats for plotting.  Naming a variable `x_axis` does not automatically make that the limits for the x-axis: that comes from the `plot` interface.  In this case, you get the line because you specified to plot a line from (0, 0) to (10, 10).